# count lower sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration

given a function

$f(x)=x, \forall x \in \mathbb{Q} ∩ [a,b] $
and $f(x)=0, \forall x \in [\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}]∩[a,b]$

for ANY partition, $P \in \mathbb{P}[a,b]$ find the lower sum $L(P.f)$

I was confused when [a, b] is an arbitrary interval.
for $a<b<0$ and $0<a<b$, I have no problem. but, if $a<0$ and $b>0$, how can we calculate the lower sum?

Comment: Are these Riemann sums for integration purposes?

Comment: yes, this is riemann sums

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a<0<b$ and let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ into subintervals $[x_0,x_1],[x_1,x_2],...,[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ (where $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n<x_{n+1}=b$). Now put $$y_k=\inf\bigl\{f(x):x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]\bigr\}$$ for integers $0\le k\le n$. There are two subcases to consider, here. If $x_n\le 0,$ you'll proceed precisely as you did in the $a<b<0$ case. Suppose not, so there is some unique integer $m$ with the following properties:

- $0\le m<n$
- $x_m\le 0$
- $x_{m+1}>0$

Then $y_k=x_k$ for $0\le k\le m$ and $y_k=0$ for $k>m$. Hence, $$L(P,f)=\sum_{k=0}^ny_k\cdot(x_{k+1}-x_k)=\sum_{k=0}^mx_k\cdot(x_{k+1}-x_k).$$

I really don't see a way around the casewise approach, here, I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks for your solution... i'll try this.... sorry for my bad english

Comment: No problem at all. I understood perfectly.